Pronunciation of "gli"
Originally when I first tried to learn it, I was pronouncing "gli" like an L with my tongue pointing downwards but recently when listening to some audio I thought it didn't match up quite right. So I watched another tutorial and landed on a sort of deeper Y sound at the top of my mouth. I also feel like hearing slightly different regional pronunciations are also messing it up in my head as to how to do it. If y'all don't mind, could you guys listen to the quick couple seconds audio where I do my initial pronunciation first and the new one second and tell me which one is more accurate and if there's still any improvements to be made. Thank you :)!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UAQuX3pAMZJuG8RewAZBto1MANQG65r7/view?usp=sharing

The first one is definitely the most accurate. I think the pronunciation in that one wouldn't raise an eyebrow, and it's enough for all learning purposes. The second one feels a lot more like a /j/ sound, which reminds one of some regional pronunciations but I would mostly consider it ``wrong''.
For what is worth, when I pronounce the /ʎ/ sound my tongue touches the soft palate with the body and below the bottom teeth with the tip. However I don't think it worthwhile to try to improve further your pronunciation, which is already significantly better than most learners.
